# how to do make_install to target in linux

Tags: linux, makefile

I am trying to make a project (gloox) for a linux target board.
I changed the makefile to use the toolchain of the target.
After make I should run

```
make install.
```

What should I do in order to install it correctly on the target?

Comment: `make install` should correctly install (assuming your Makefile is kosher). What is your problem?

Comment: I am making a standard project, not made by me. So I assume it should be compiled and installed correctly on a PC. But I need it to run on a target...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most makefiles accept `make DESTDIR=<path> install`. This should work for Gloox, seeing that it uses autotools to generate the makefile.

(Normally you do not need to edit the makefile in order to use toolchain for a different architecture; `./configure` accepts options `--build` and `--target`.)